# How to connect to S3 Bucket providing credentials using Nodejs version 3 sdk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to send some simple text to a S3 Bucket. I have attempted to create a connection to the bucket using NodeJS and the V3 SDK. Unfortunately, I get an exception indicating I am missing a credential provider. Here is my code:

```js
      import connProperties from "./myprops";
      import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand, PutObjectCommand, PutObjectCommandInput } from 
                                                      "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
      import {EndpointV2} from '@aws-sdk/types'
      import AWS from "aws-sdk";

      const connect = async() =>{


      if(connProperties.isValidProps()){
       const endPoint: EndpointV2  = {url: new URL('http://my-s3-bucket-site.com')} as 
        EndpointV2 
     
       const bucketProps = {
         Bucket: 'data-log',
         region: 'us-east-1',
         endpoint: endPoint,
         accessKeyId: 'qys4ddggd',
         secretAccessKey: 'mysecretkryvalie'
       } 
       const command = new PutObjectCommand({
          Bucket: 'data-log',
          Key: "test-s3.txt",
          Body: "This is some text!",
        });
   
         const s3client = new S3Client(bucketProps);
         s3client.send(command); 
      }else{
        console.log('Cannot send to S3 Bucket');
      }
    }
```

I have no idea how to provide the credentials, the document has no examples which do that. Here is the exception I get:

{"timestamp":"2023-04-13T15:16:21.347Z","message":"This exception is:  CredentialsProviderError: Could not load credentials from any providers\n"}

This did not work for me either:  ~/.aws/credentials

```json
  
  [default]
  aws_access_key_id = <my-access-key>
  aws_secret_access_key = <my-secret-key>
```

The error is {"timestamp":"2023-04-13T16:17:04.166Z","message":"The output Error: unable to verify the first certificate\n"}

Comment: What's the compute context?  Local CLI with aws credentials configured, Lambda function, EC2 instance,  Docker container?

Comment: The [S3Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/s3client.html) doesn't take 'bucket properties' as a parameter. It takes an [S3ClientConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/s3clientconfig.html).

Comment: There's fairly thorough documentation, starting at [Setting Credentials in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey` belong in the `credentials` property like so:

```js
const bucketProps = {
    region: 'us-east-1',
    endpoint: endPoint,
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: 'qys4ddggd',
        secretAccessKey: 'mysecretkryvalie'
    }
}
```

Also the `Bucket` key does not exist in this `S3Client` config object, you only pass it when creating a command.

As for the `endpoint`, the [S3 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/s3clientconfig.html#endpoint) state:

> This is only for using a custom endpoint (for example, when using a local version of S3).

I'm not sure if that's what you need.

And as a side note, while this is not an issue for testing, it's a best practice to not store these **secret** keys in code. You can for example load them from a `.env` file using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Comment: I am storing them in a dotenv. This is just attempting to get the credentials problem fixed.

Comment: I discovered that my attempts were failing because of a certificate in NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS not passing verification. I turned that off using NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 briefly and it worked.

Comment: @BreenDeen be aware that you're making some questionable security decisions here: including credentials inline in your code and not verifying TLS/SSL certificates.

Answer (score 0):

This is all documented in the [AWS SDK Guide for JavaScrip](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html)t. I am not sure which  AWS Doc you are looking at, but this is docuemnted here:

[Loading credentials in Node.js from the shared credentials file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html)

Its a good idea to use this DEV guide when working with AWS SDK for JavaScript V3.

Refer to this Github for JS code examples:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascriptv3/example_code/s3/scenarios/basic.js

Comment: This example does not show how to load credentials, unfortunately that's where the error is coming from. Using the ~/.was/credentials seems to think the  aws_access_key_id is a certificate?

Comment: Follow the directions in the 2nd link i provided